# App will not randomize the next image on ImageView, tag Array is not synced with the Imageview. How do I fix this?

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, imageview

When I run this app the first sign is loaded into the ImageView, it's tag matches the text in a particular button.

Then I have a method (at the bottom) where it is supposed to randomly pick the next image from an array, and the corresponding String from an ArrayList.

**The problem is after the first answer, it will not load a new image.**

***But apparently changes the tag as it will tell me it is wrong in a Toast. How do I fix this?***

```
package com.example.roadsignquiz;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ArrayList<String> answersArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> randomAnswerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<String> tagArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    int signIndex;
    Random random = new Random();
    Button button1;
    Button button2;
    Button button3;
    Button button4;
    Button button5;
    Button button6;
    Button button7;
    ImageView signImage;
    int answer1;
    int answer2;
    int answer3;
    int answer4;
    int answer5;
    int answer6;
    int answer7;
    int randomPicIndex = random.nextInt(7);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        signImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.signImageView);
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            randomAnswerList.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
        }
        Collections.shuffle(randomAnswerList);
        answer1 = randomAnswerList.get(1);
        answer2 = randomAnswerList.get(2);
        answer3 = randomAnswerList.get(3);
        answer4 = randomAnswerList.get(4);
        answer5 = randomAnswerList.get(5);
        answer6 = randomAnswerList.get(6);
        answer7 = randomAnswerList.get(0);

        answersArray.add("No Parking"); // 0
        answersArray.add("Stop Sign"); // 1
        answersArray.add("Yield Sign"); // 2
        answersArray.add("Pedestrian Crossing");// 3
        answersArray.add("No U Turn"); // 4
        answersArray.add("One Way"); // 5
        answersArray.add("Speed Limit Sign"); // 6

        tagArray.add("No Parking");
        tagArray.add("Stop Sign");
        tagArray.add("Yield Sign");
        tagArray.add("Pedestrian Crossing");
        tagArray.add("No U Turn");
        tagArray.add("One Way");
        tagArray.add("Speed Limit Sign");

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setText(answersArray.get(answer1));

        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setText(answersArray.get(answer2));

        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button3.setText(answersArray.get(answer3));

        button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button4.setText(answersArray.get(answer4));

        button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        button5.setText(answersArray.get(answer5));

        button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        button6.setText(answersArray.get(answer6));

        button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        button7.setText(answersArray.get(answer7));

        signImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop_sign);
        signImage.setTag("Stop Sign");

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (signImage.getTag() == button1.getText()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    NextPicture();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wrongo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }); // end button1 onClickListener

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (signImage.getTag() == button2.getText()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    NextPicture();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wrongo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }); // end button2 onClickListener

        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (signImage.getTag() == button3.getText()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    NextPicture();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wrongo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }); // end button3 onClickListener

        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (signImage.getTag() == button4.getText()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    NextPicture();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wrongo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }); // end button4 onClickListener

        button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (signImage.getTag() == button5.getText()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    NextPicture();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wrongo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }); // end button5 onClickListener

        button6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (signImage.getTag() == button6.getText()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    NextPicture();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wrongo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }); // end button6 onClickListener

        button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (signImage.getTag() == button7.getText()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    NextPicture();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wrongo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }); // end button7 onClickListener

    }

    public void NextPicture() {
        int[] signsArray = { R.drawable.no_parking, R.drawable.no_u_turn_sign, R.drawable.one_way_sign,
                R.drawable.pedestrian_crossing, R.drawable.speed_limit_sign, R.drawable.stop_sign,
                R.drawable.yield_sign };
        signImage.setImageResource(signsArray[randomPicIndex]);
        signImage.setTag(tagArray.get(randomPicIndex));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are ever changing your random index. You need to add `randomPicIndex = random.nextInt(7);` to your `NextPicture()`. Also,
you can't compare strings with `==`. Use `.equals()` instead.

```
public void NextPicture() {
    int[] signsArray = { R.drawable.no_parking, R.drawable.no_u_turn_sign, R.drawable.one_way_sign,
            R.drawable.pedestrian_crossing, R.drawable.speed_limit_sign, R.drawable.stop_sign,
            R.drawable.yield_sign };
    randomPicIndex = random.nextInt(7);
    signImage.setImageResource(signsArray[randomPicIndex]);
    signImage.setTag(tagArray.get(randomPicIndex));

}
```

To simplify everything assign the same click listener to each button since they all follow the same logic.

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (((String) signImage.getTag()).equals(((Button) v).getText())) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            NextPicture();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wrongo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
};
button1.setOnClickListener(listener);
button2.setOnClickListener(listener);
...
```

Comment: Great, thanks so much! After making these changes the ImageView will change pictures, however even when clicking the correct button, it will still (mostly) throw a wrong answer message.

Comment: Check your `signsArray`. I think you may have a couple in the wrong order compared to the answers.

Comment: Yep that was it exactly. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your issue. Up-votes are always appreciated as well :)